# How do I fix ORA-04091: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to create a trigger that makes the value of trgr equal to the value of seq+100 on the same row. This is what I did but I keep getting the error "table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_tgr
AFTER INSERT ON challenge FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE challenge
        SET trgr = :NEW.seq + 100
        WHERE seq = :NEW.seq;
END;
```

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The same row? That is simply:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_tgr
BEFORE INSERT ON challenge FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.trgr := :NEW.seq + 100;
END;
```

You see you should use a **BEFORE** INSERT trigger, because then you are still able to manipulate the new data.

Comment: You cannot get that error with this trigger. Maybe there is another trigger invoking the error?

Comment: I don't have any other triggers

Comment: Have you really removed your update statement and replaced it with the simple assignment as shown?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to activate it with this:
INSERT INTO challenge VALUES ( 4, null );

seq is 4 and trigger is null

Comment: As mentioned, this trigger cannot lead to a mutating table error. So, as you say there is no other trigger, it must be that the old trigger has not been replaced by the new one.

Comment: I already compiled it and it says "Trigger UPDATE_TGR compiled"

Comment: Hm, sorry, no idea. The trigger I have shown cannot produce this error. You can see the active trigger code with `select text from user_source where name = 'UPDATE_TGR' order by line;`.

Comment: @Laura I just created the table, created the trigger and inserted a row, all fine, no errors. You must have a second trigger or something.

Answer (score 1):

I think creating a `Virtual Column` is a better option if your DB version is 11g+. Since no need to store a column on disk which can already been computed. This prevents inserting wrong values possibility for the column (`trgr`) unlike traditional definition style. Then, you can recreate your table such as

```
CREATE TABLE challenge (
  .....
  seq         INT,
  trgr        AS (seq + 100), -- [VIRTUAL]
  ----
);
```

no need to bother about the data type which is already determined based on the result of the expression(`INT`). You can query the the like an ordinary table

Comment: Yes, this is the better option as long as the trigger is not just about an initial value that is allowed to be altered later.